# How to show user activity in modal by django-activity-stream app?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.10, django-activity-stream

Can someone who worked with app [django-activity-stream](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream) say me how to use it correctly by example? I am really comfused after reading the documentation.

I need to show last 10 activity which was in my modal `Characterictic`. User can edit Characterictic objects also add comments to objects.

**For example**:

```
1) User A add comment to Characterictic B in 11:45
2) User B edit Characterictic C in 11:00
3) User C create Characterictic А in 09:55.
```

**models.py:**

```
class Characteristic(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    symbol = models.CharField(_('Symbol'), max_length=250)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'))
    comments = models.ManyToManyField("Comment")
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(_('Date of creation'), auto_now_add=True)
    revision_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date of last update'), auto_now=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```